# Dynamically add text/data to a DocuSign template

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm implementing an API that is written in C# using ASP.NET Web API. The implementation of our API calls out to DocuSign e.g. in order to request signatures for contracts. Our application interacts with DocuSign through its REST API.

I would like to be able to create a template for our contract document and then simply reference this template when sending the contract via the REST API.

The issue I have is that the contract document needs to include data that is queried from our database, e.g. a list of products that are specific to a recipient.

Is it possible to add placeholders in the template that can then be replaced, via the REST API, with recipient-specific text/data that is queried from a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is easy to do through the API.  Let's say you want to get a person's name and SSN and have a template that has two data fields in it called `ApplicantName` and `ApplicantSSN`.  By referring to the `tabLabel` of each you can dynamically set their values, so for instance:

```
{
    "accountId": "221765",
    "emailSubject": "DocuSign API Example",
    "templateId": "44D9E888-3D86-4186-8EE9-7071BC87A0DA",
    "templateRoles": [
        {
            "email": "sally.doe@email.com",
            "name": "Sally Doe",
            "roleName": "RoleOne",
            "tabs": {
                "textTabs": [
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "ApplicantName",
                        "value": "John Doe"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "ApplicantSSN",
                        "value": "12-345-6789"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Just make sure you exactly match the name you set in the UI with the `tabLabel` you set through the API call.